# Why can't you install Geopandas in the base environment?

Tags: pandas, geopandas

Why do we have to create a virtual environment to get the package.

Comment: just in the past week answering SO questions, I have come across 4 different dependencies that don't work.  Hence if I wasn't using virtual envs I would have had to completely rebuild my python environment 4 times.  It's far simpler to tear down a venv and rebuild (2 mins vs 1hr +)

Comment: Yeah the technical answer to your question is "you can install it in your base env, but you probably shouldn't". Geopandas is a very complex library with lots of python and non-python dependencies. Anything installed in your base env runs the risk of being available in base and also in your named envs (if not overridden). So if you have another environment where you have not installed gdal or some other dependency and then you accidentally import it you'll get into a terrible dependency conflict state with mixed environments. Other problems can happen too but that's an easy one to explain.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use some form of virtual environment for each project. Different libraries have different dependencies at specific version ranges for other libraries. So when you have a combination of packages you should use something to keep track of all those versions.

This might not feel like a problem when you're first starting out, but over time you will have older projects and projects with very different dependency sets. Then you won't want your base environment all messed up with version conflicts.

Two good options:

1. Use `pyenv` to switch between Python versions and `Poetry` to manage virtual environments & dependencies (my personal favourite)
2. Use `anaconda` which does all three (python versions, handles dependency conflicts, and has virtual environments)

Comment: Thanks. Will make sure to do the same now on.